# sparkR-Mongo connector query to subdocument

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, connector

I am using Mongo-Spark connector all examples in documentation (https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/sparkR/) are fine, but if I test query in a document which has subdocuments it fails, obviously SQL is not ready for this query:

```
result <- sql(sqlContext, "SELECT DOCUMENT.SUBDOCUMENT FROM TABLE")
```

ERROR:

```
com.mongodb.spark.exceptions.MongoTypeConversionException: Cannot cast INT32 into a ConflictType (value: BsonInt32{value=171609012})
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$.com$mongodb$spark$sql$MapFunctions$$convertToDataType(MapFunctions.scala:79)
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$$anonfun$3.apply(MapFunctions.scala:38)
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$$anonfun$3.apply(MapFunctions.scala:36)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$.documentToRow(MapFunctions.scala:36)
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$.castToStructType(MapFunctions.scala:108)
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$.com$mongodb$spark$sql$MapFunctions$$convertToDataType(MapFunctions.scala:74)
```

Previously I have registered the table as follow:

```
registerTempTable(schema, "TABLE")
```

I guess that the key problem is how to register an mongo-subdocument as table.

Someone has the solution?

Comment: Could you please show us a sample document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: All fields must follow the same type, I had fields in String type and others in Double type for this reason table is registered but it can´t be process.